# How do I change the font of a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game similar to cookie clicker. This is part of my code:

```js
 var clicks = 0;
function updateClickCount() {
  document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="game-object">    
  <button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push" style="width:400px;height:60px;">
    <font size="5" face="verdana" color="white">Click me for Cola!</font>
   </button>
   <div id="clickCount"></div>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

I want to make the variable that appears on the screen after clicking the button a different font. I also want to know how to make it different colors.

Comment: css, style the html element to what you want

Comment: I think he wants to do it with javascript, to change the font dynamically, is that right?

Comment: I think you are studying from a book written in 2005. Do not use `center` (also, you seem to have forgotten to close that tag). Do not use the `font` tag--we use CSS for that these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution giving your number a random new color on every click. I've changed the html from inline javascript to using an eventListener, which is what you want to use in real life

```js
var clicks = 0;

document.getElementById("push").addEventListener("click", updateClickCount);

function updateClickCount() {
 clicks++;
 var el = document.getElementById("clickCount");
  el.innerHTML = clicks;
  el.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="push">Click me for Cola!</font></button>
<div id="clickCount"></div>
```

Attribution: random color creation by [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not expect to get answers beyond what I was even expecting in so little time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to style the element:

```
<style>
    #clickCount {
        color: red;
        font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can add a function that is called on click which can update your
>   css. Try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Click me </button>


 function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById('clickCount').setAttribute("class", "style1");
    }
```

Here is some more info on .setAttribue: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute