# Javascript/Html: How do I change the size of the font/font itself, not just the color?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a chunk of code I have that creates a button which adds to a variable that is made visible. I would like to be able to know how to change the font size of the displayed variable. I am making a game similar to cookie clicker.

```
<div class="game-object">
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;

document.getElementById("push").addEventListener("click", updateClickCount);

function updateClickCount() {
var el = document.getElementById("clickCount");
el.innerHTML = clicks;
el.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push" style="width:400px;height:60px;"><font size="5" face="verdana" color="white">Click me for Cola!</font></button>
<div id="clickCount"></div>
```

How do you set the font size of the variable, and how do you change the font?

Comment: This question shows very little research effort.  This is covered in lots of tutorials and documentation.  e.g. `el.style.fontSize = "220px";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [said earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102163/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-javascript-variable), don't use inline javascript (nor inline css). To change the font-size, simply use `el.style.fontSize`

```js
var clicks = 0;

document.getElementById("push").addEventListener("click", updateClickCount);

function updateClickCount() {
var el = document.getElementById("clickCount");
clicks++;
el.innerHTML = clicks;
el.style.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
el.style.fontSize = '200px';
}
```

```css
#push {
  width:400px;
  height:60px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-object"></div>


<button type="button" id="push">Click me for Cola!</button>
<div id="clickCount"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for second answer today!